# Yii Framework, вывод ссылки только на главной

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста как можно определить что пользователь на главной странице? Что только не пробовал, всё равно где-то даёт сбой, где-то видно ссылку(и я был не на главной странице), и если можно подскажите как это реализовать в Yii Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Yii::app()->controller->id // название контроллера
Yii::app()->controller->action->id // Название экшена
```

Делаем проверку

```
if(Yii::app()->controller->id == 'Контроллер' and Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'Метод')
{
// выводим ссылку
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, такую проверку я смог сделать, но у меня 2 варианта главной страницы:

1) http://site.ru/
2) http://site.ru/index.php/site/index

И вот как отловить первый вариант, я не знаю(

Comment: Какой бы вариант УРЛА не использовался, контроллер и метод остается не измененным.